# Triangular numbers and the harmonic mean

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

This morning somebody called my attention to the fact that $4T_n$ is the harmonic mean of $T_{2n}$ and $T_{2n+1}$, where $T_n=n(n+1)/2$ is the $n$th triangular number.  I verified this algebraically but -

> Do you know a *conceptual* reason why this is happening?

It makes sense to me that $4T_n$ sits between $T_{2n}$ and $T_{2n+1}$ in *some* sort of nice way, since $T_{2n}=3T_n+T_{n-1}$ and $T_{2n+1}=3T_n + T_{n+1}$.  But why the harmonic mean?

Comment: Do you have, or know of, any conceptual understanding of the harmonic mean at all?

Comment: The best *conceptual* explanation I can think of is introducing geometry to graphically explain this.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - The only conceptual understanding of the harmonic mean I have is this: if $x,y$ are my average speeds on the outbound and return legs of a trip, respectively, then the harmonic mean of $x,y$ is my average speed on the whole trip.

Comment: @chubakueno - that sounds great. What specifically do you have in mind?

Comment: Ben, that's a nice way to understand the harmonic mean, but (other than doing the algebra) I really can't see why, if your outbound speed is a triangular number, and your return speed is the next triangular number, your average speed should be 4 times some other triangular number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - yes, neither can I. This is why I posted a question.  I am hoping that somebody on the site either has an interpretation of triangular numbers in terms of speed that is illuminating, or else a different conceptual picture for the harmonic mean, or some other shift in point of view that will help.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Thanks.